# Помогите с зданием на Яндекс.Практикум

Tags: python, join

Задание:

> В этой задаче вам дан словарь, в котором ключи — имена друзей, а значения — списки любимых песен каждого друга.
>
> Напечатайте на экран:
>
> Количество любимых песен Димы.
>
> Все любимые песни Сони через запятую и пробел.

```
    favorite_songs = {
        'Серёга': ["Unforgiven", "Holiday", "Highway to hell"], 
        'Соня': ["Shake it out", "Don't stop me now", "Наше лето"], 
        'Дима': ["Владимирский централ", "Мурка", "Третье сентября"]
    }
    
    print (len(favorite_songs["Дима"]))
    
    print(favorite_songs["Соня"]+", ".join(favorite_songs["Соня"]))
```

Ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(favorite_songs["Соня"]+", ".join(favorite_songs["Соня"]))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: `favorite_songs["Соня"]+` — а какую задачу решает этот кусок кода?

Comment: Напечатайте на экран, как Серега и Дима уживаются в одной компании с такими разными музыкальными вкусами.

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка происходит потому, что Вы пытаетесь сложить список (`list`) со строкой (`str`). Так делать нельзя. Вам придётся привести один тип к другому. Например, список к строке:

```py
type(favorite_songs['Соня'])             # list
type(", ".join(favorite_songs['Соня']))  # str

print(str(favorite_songs['Соня']) + ", ".join(favorite_songs['Соня']))
#     ^^^^                      ^
```

```html
['Shake it out', "Don't stop me now", 'Наше лето']Shake it out, Don't stop me now, Наше лето
```

---

Но я не понимаю, зачем Вам это нужно. По условию задачи достаточно только части с методом `join`:

```py
favorite_songs = {
    'Серёга': ["Unforgiven", "Holiday", "Highway to hell"], 
    'Соня': ["Shake it out", "Don't stop me now", "Наше лето"], 
    'Дима': ["Владимирский централ", "Мурка", "Третье сентября"],
}
    
print(len(favorite_songs['Дима']))
print(", ".join(favorite_songs['Соня']))
```

***stdout:***

```html
3
Shake it out, Don't stop me now, Наше лето
```

Answer (score 0):

```
favorite_songs = {
    'Серёга': ['Unforgiven', 'Holiday', 'Highway to hell'], 
    'Соня': ['Shake it out', 'The Show Must Go On', 'Наше лето'], 
    'Дима': ['Владимирский централ', 'Мурка', 'Третье сентября']
}

number_dima = len(favorite_songs['Дима'])
print(number_dima)
   
for songs in favorite_songs.values():
    favorit_sonya = favorite_songs['Соня']
for i in favorit_sonya:
    print(i)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
print(len(favorite_songs['Дима']))

songs = favorite_songs['Соня']

for song in songs:
 
    print(song)
```

Результат

3

Shake it out

The Show Must Go On

Наше лето

Comment: и что должно значить то, что вы написали? к вопросу оно явно не имеет отношения.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).